# expected content type in console window

Tags: iphone, ios, drupal

While trying [workhabitinc](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=workhabitinc%20%2b%20git%20%2b%20drupal%20examples&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAB&url=https://github.com/workhabitinc/drupal-ios-sdk-example&ei=G2FQUO6ELs_irAeF7oDgAQ&usg=AFQjCNGZOQyKrKicV8si46eq1dzC2ozKpw&sig2=n4uOFMcz8qf9kvEjLDbT9w) sample code about Dupal i got the following in **console window**

```
  2012-09-12 15:00:36.751 Drupal Questions[3156:c07] Expected content type {(
        "text/json",
        "text/javascript",
        "application/json",
        "text/plain"
    )},
```

I am new to  drupal and was not able to understand this.. is this related to **setting.h** (or any configuration) ?

In README file there is a point "**Update Settings.h with the correct correct url and endpoints)**" what does this mean? and

What are all i am supposed to add to project other than **drupal sdk** and **AFNetworking** files?

Any help much appreciated  :)

Comment: http://www.zivtech.com/blog/simplest-drupal-iphone-app may be this link is very helpful.Download the Zip file.If it helps give Upvote

Comment: @MedetiNaveenKumar nice tutorial.. i have downloaded the code and as i have not yet installed services i am unable to get complete output.. if you have any idea about endpoint and services please can you share?

Comment: you can get response by using get methods but be care with service.Just check the sdk carefully.You can understand what's the process is going on...

Comment: @MedetiNaveenKumar please can you tell how to get response by get methods, i tried Configuring Drupal 7.x with Services 3.x and OAuth as in http://drupal.org/node/942866 this link , but i am confused what to specify in callback URL.. do u have any idea?